# Theorem 5.8 Baby Rudin. Some questions

Tags: real-analysis

This is with reference to the page number 107 of Baby Rudin.

> Theorem 5.8 Let $f$ be defined on $[a,b]$.If a point $x\in(a,b)$ is a
>   local maximum of function $f$, and if $f'(x)$ exist, then $f'(x)=0$.

I have some questions. Thanks in advance for reading and helping out.

1. What about the converse of this theorem? Suppose $f'(x)=0$ at some point, can we always conclude that it is local maximum?
2. The theorem add a condition that $f'(x)$ should exist. This raised a question, Can we have a function function with local maximum/minimum at some point say $p$ but derivative undefined at the point.

Edits:

We can take $f(x)=x^2$ on $[-1,1]$. $f'(0)=0$ but $0$  is not local maximum. I think this works for (1).

Answer (score 9):

**Answer to question 1**

The derivative of $f(x)=x^3$ vanishes at $0$ but $f$ doesn’t have a minimum nor at maximum at $0$.

**Answer to question 2**

Take $g(x)=\vert x \vert$, again look at zero.

Answer (score 5):

If $f'(x)=0$, then $x$ is said to be a stationary point. It can be something like $x=0$ in $f(x)=x^3$ too, for example.

For (2), we can even have a function with a global maximum at $p$ but without a derivative in this point. See, for example, $f(x)=-|x|$.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What about the converse of this theorem? Suppose $f'(x)=0$ at some point, can we always conclude that it is local maximum?

No. It could be a minimum, or it could be neither. Such examples:

- $f(x) = x^2$. Here, $f'(x) = 2x$ thus implying $f'(x) = 0$ for $x = 0$. It is immediately clear on looking at the graph that this is a local minimum for some intervals of the function.
- $f(x) = x^3$. Here, $f'(x) = 3x^2$. Thus, $f'(x) = 0$ only if $x=0$. On looking at the graph, it is clearly not a local extremum in either respect, up to choice of the interval.

(I say "up to choice of the interval" because $x=0$ yields a local minimum on the choice of interval $[0,1]$ for both functions, and on $[-1,0]$ for example the latter has a maximum instead. If we generally state intervals $[a,b]$ with $a<0<b$, though, they respectively have a minimum and neither respectively at $x=0$.)

This touches on the nature of "critical points" you might have learned in your introductory calculus courses: points where $f'(x) = 0$ or is undefined are candidates for local extrema.

---

> 2. The theorem add a condition that $f'(x)$ should exist. This raised a question, Can we have a function with local maximum/minimum at some point say $p$ but derivative undefined at the point?

Yes. Consider $f(x) = |x|$ on the interval $[a,b]$ where $a<0<b$. The function clearly has a minimum at $x=0$, but the derivative is undefined at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try:

1) $f'(x)=0; $

Example:$ f(x)=x^3$, at $x= 0$,  inflection point, not an extremum

2) $f(x)= |x|$ , has a local minimum at $x=0.$

$f(x)= -|x|$ has a local maximum at $x=0$

(f'(0) does not exist)(Why?)

Comment: $f'(0)$ does not exist because RHD and LHD are not equal. If we take difference coefficient $f(x)-f(0)/(x-0) $ then depending upon from where we approach $0$ we get two different limits. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Stammering.Yes,exactly!!Greetings.